# Disable prompt login in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an intranet c# application it's single sign on when I published it on iis the browser displaying prompt login, How I can disable it.

web.config

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

Comment: I tried in IE and chrome

Answer (score 1):

Check your Internet Options Local intranet zone and see if Auto Logon is selected. This setting also affects other browsers, not just IE.
[image]

Comment: @Anwar your application ip address or domain name also needs to be in the Trusted Sites section. I think addresses on the same subnet should automatically be trusted but try putting it into the Trusted Sites and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try add [DisableLoopbackCheck](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.000102594) to registry if you are running on local comp. I spent 2 days with this. Also reboot the comp after it.